# Bash: How to catch error from AWS Cli command?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-secrets-manager

I'm trying to do a `try/except` in my bash script. Basically, I just want to retrieve a secret from SecretsManager, and check if the cli command raises an error.

I tried something like this but it errors out before it flows through the if/else

```
  command=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id ${secret_name} --query SecretString --output text | jq . 2>&1)
  if [[ "${command}" =~ "An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException)" ]]; then
    echo "Configuration does not exist in SecretsManager. Unable to initialize Metaflow settings"
  else
    echo "Configuration exists in SecretsManager. Initializing Metaflow settings"
    echo ${command} > ~/.metaflowconfig/config.json
  fi
```

The desired result would be to check if the cli command returns an error. If it does not, then set the secret to local config file. If it does, then print that "Unable to initialize settings".

Comment: looking at your history, looks like you're pretty familiar with python.  Having around 10 yrs experience with the aws cli, I strongly suggest you use `boto3` and python to do this.  boto3 doesn't have any strange requirements and is just a `pip` away.  It can be done in `bash` but it's really a pain compared to python and `boto3`.

Comment: `it doesn't seem to work` what does this mean?

Comment: It means it errors out before it flows through the if/else

Comment: Any particular reason you're using `command_output` in one place, and `command` in another?

Comment: Oh oops - good catch. Typo

Comment: Also your code asks for text output and then pipes the output to `jq`. Even though SecretsManager is gnarly and might actually output something like JSON for `--output text`, does the CLI do that if the result is an error?

Comment: Finally, [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/return-codes.html) indicates the exit status should broadly indicate if the result is an error or not. Is there some reason that is not useful here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem of your script is that you are piping the output of the CLI command directly to `jq`, which prevents your logic from working correctly. Here's how I would do it:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
secret_name="..."
command_output=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id $secret_name --query SecretString --output text 2>&1)
command_exit_code=$?

if [[ "$command_exit_code" -ne 0 ]]; then
  if [[ "${command_output}" =~ "An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException)" ]]; then
    echo "Configuration does not exist in SecretsManager. Unable to initialize Metaflow settings"
  fi
  # other error cases you might want to deal with
else
    echo "Configuration exists in SecretsManager. Initializing Metaflow settings"
    echo "${command_output}" | jq '.' > ~/.metaflowconfig/config.json
fi
```